# Different count amount using grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to modify this SQL query:

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT contacts) AS Totaly
FROM   clicks
WHERE  clicks.campaign_id = 1234
       AND clicks.type IN ( 1, 2, 3 )
```

To get clicks per day. I created this:

```
SELECT Cast(clicks.time AS DATE) AS 'date',
       
----- THE SAME CODE -----
Count(DISTINCT contacts) AS Totaly
FROM   clicks
WHERE  clicks.campaign_id = 1234
       AND clicks.type IN ( 1, 2, 3 )
----- THE SAME CODE -----
        
GROUP  BY Cast(clicks.time AS DATE)
```

The problem is that count of records from second query is not the same as from first query. I can check that with this:

```sql
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Cast(clicks.time AS DATE) AS 'date',
                
                ----- THE SAME CODE -----
                Count(DISTINCT contacts) AS Totaly
         FROM   clicks
         WHERE  clicks.campaign_id = 1234
                AND clicks.type IN ( 1, 2, 3 )
                ----- THE SAME CODE -----
                
         GROUP  BY Cast(clicks.time AS DATE))
SELECT Sum(totaly)
FROM   cte
```

So my question is - why I am not getting the same sum?

Comment: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: If you have A, B, C in day one, and B, C, D in day two, you have 4 distinct values overall, but 3 distinct values in each day ('totalling' 6).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The numbers *are not* comparable. `COUNT(DISTINCT)` counts the number of *distinct* different values in the group, when you change the grouping you will change the overall total because they are no longer counting the same distinct items.

For your queries your first simply `COUNT`s the `DISTINCT` values of `contacts`. There is no `GROUP BY` so this is based purely on the whole data set. For the second query you are `COUNT`ing the number of `DISTINCT` values of `contacts` *per* date. This means that the *same* value of `contacts` can (and will) be counted more than once *if* they appear on different dates. AS a result when you `SUM` the `COUNT` from your second query you get a `COUNT` of distinct `contacts` ***and*** dates.

Let's take this very overly simplified example data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (ContactID int,
                            SomeDate date);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (ContactID,
                           SomeDate)
VALUES(1,'20230101'),
      (1,'20230102'),
      (2,'20230102'),
      (3,'20230103'),
      (3,'20230104');
```

Now, very clearly, we can see that there are 3 different values for `ContactId`, however, we can verify this:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ContactID)
FROM dbo.SomeTable;
```

Now let's get a `DISTINCT` `COUNT` of `ContactID` for each value of `SomeDate`. This will give us the following result:

| SomeDate | DistinctContacts |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 1 |
| 2023-01-02 | 2 |
| 2023-01-03 | 1 |
| 2023-01-04 | 1 |

And to verify:

```sql
SELECT SomeDate,
       COUNT(DISTINCT ContactID) AS DistinctContacts
FROM dbo.SomeTable
GROUP BY SomeDate;
```

So we can clearly see that the total, `5`, here is quite different but it isstill correct. The total is now representative of the `DISTINCT` values of `contactID` *and* `SomeDate`.

If you wanted to get both the `DISTINCT` count by `SomeDate` *and* the total you could use `ROLLUP` or `GROUING SETS`. I demonstrate both, however, due to the over simplification they return the same result; for other queries they might not (as `ROLLUP` might include more groups):

```sql
SELECT SomeDate,
       COUNT(DISTINCT ContactID) AS DistinctContacts
FROM dbo.SomeTable
GROUP BY SomeDate
WITH ROLLUP;

SELECT SomeDate,
       COUNT(DISTINCT ContactID) AS DistinctContacts
FROM dbo.SomeTable
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((SomeDate),());
```

This returns the following:

| SomeDate | DistinctContacts |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 1 |
| 2023-01-02 | 2 |
| 2023-01-03 | 1 |
| 2023-01-04 | 1 |
| NULL | 3 |

Note that for the row where `SomeDate` has the value `NULL` `3` is returned, *not* `5`.